# API Gateway variable number of path parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

Is it possible to have a variable number of path parameters on an API gateway URL?

i.e. APIGW runs theoretical lambda function that sums numbers in a URL:

```
/dev/myservice/sum/1/2 => sum(1,2) => 3
/dev/myservice/sum/1/2/3/3/3 => sum(1,2,3,3,3) => 12
```

If this is possible, then how do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use greedy path variables like /myservice/sum/{proxy+} and the lambda proxy integration (used by the serveless framework) to solve this use case.

Comment: do you have any documentation for this? I'm trying to test your suggestion, and I'm getting an error indicative of it not respecting the greedy path variables: `missing authentication token`

Comment: Running locally with `serverless-offline` doesn't work right; it's URL-encoding the slashes

Answer (score 3):

You can use the standard API Gateway proxy features, no need to use the serverless framework (although the framework is great for other reasons).

In the console it's pretty easy, this guide should take you through the setup. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html